# Why does "await client.say()" doesn't work in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with python 3.6 and discord.py for my personal discord server, and I made a "help" command the only thing which is not working is the `await client.say()`. I use cogs, I currently have 3 files named `basics.py`, `info_commands.py` and `miscellaneous.py`

I tried to replace `await client.say()` with `await client.send_message()` but still doesn't work. I don't understand why because it work anywhere else in my code and the error message doesn't really help me.

```
cogs = ['info_commands', 'miscellaneous']

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    help = discord.Embed(title="Voici le menu d'aide :", description="", 
color=discord.Colour.dark_red())
    for y in range(len(cogs)):
        help.add_field(name=str(cogs[y-1]), value="", inline=True)

    await client.say(embed=help)
```

The expected result is an embed with two field, first `miscellaneous` and second `info_commands` but the current result is an error message which says that there is an error at line 34 in help, here's the error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: You should be getting an error for trying to register a `help` command.  Are you doing something to remove the existing `help` command?

Comment: Yes I removed the default help command with `client.remove_command('help')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an empty `value` in an embed field. Instead, you can have a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space),

```
help.add_field(name=str(cogs[y-1]), value="\u200b", inline=True)
```

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, thanks a lot ! I'll try when i'll be on my PC tomorrow